# Retorna Excel em Lista C# esta retornando nulo

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel, null

Esse código faz a leitura de um arquivo `Excel` e joga uma lista, o problema que está ocorrendo é ele está retornando ***nulo***, como se não houvesse nada no `Excel`, porem os nomes das colunas estão corretos:

```
string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + local + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\";";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
string sqlCommand = "Select * From [Plan1$]";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
List<Entidades> listaComentario = new List<Entidades>();

try
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (rd.Read())
    {
        listaComentario.Add(new Entidades()
        {
            PNR = rd[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PNR"]].ToString(),
            Status = rd[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Status"]].ToString(),
        });
    }

    if (listaComentario.Count() > 0)
        return listaComentario;
    else
        return null;

}
```

Comment: Você tentou *debugar*? Sabe se ele nem entra no `while`? Tente isolar mais o problema.

Comment: Remova o block try catch para verificar melhor o erro. Depois poderá retorná-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apenas para deixar registrado. Encontrei o problema. Troquei minha maquina, por uma que trabalha com processador de 64 bits. O erro, estava caindo no Catch, quando debuguei, encontrei o problema.

Estava retornando **"microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 not registrered on the local machine"**. Para corrigir, bastou instalar um Driver Data Connectivity pra 64 bits, que peguei no proprio site da Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734,

Obrigado ao a todos.